# How to get array to unlink pictures from select row using id

Tags: php, arrays, unlink

Trying to unlink pictures using an id array it deletes the accounts but not the pictures can anyone help please, the selectrow id is different from id thanks

```
$delid = $_POST['selectrow'];
$nc = count($delid);

for($i=0;$i<$nc;$i++)
{
    $did = $delid[$i];
    $a = array($eg_Result1['id']);

    foreach ($a as $v) {
        // Get the file name
        // Get the folder path
        unlink('../images/userpics/'.$v.'.png');
    }

    setcookie('selectdelete', success);

    mysqli_query( $eg_objConn1, "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `xkey` = '".$did."'");
}

// Go to page
header("Location: manage_adminpanel.php?s=".@$_COOKIE['sort']."&xpage=".@$_COOKIE['xpage']."");
exit;
```

Comment: `unlink(__DIR__ . '../images/userpics/'.$v.'.png');` ?

Comment: Do a file_exists check on the images before unlink to make sure you’re finding them.  Double check folder permissions.

Comment: Yep files exist and permissions are okay, don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Just so you know, your DELETE query is insecure.  If someone wrote the "right" value into `$_POST['selectrow']` they might be able to delete all of the rows in your table.  You should be using a prepared statement with a placeholder.  Because we cannot validate that your image file(s) exist where you say they do, this question is off-topic: cannot reproduce.

Comment: can you show your folder tree structure !

Comment: It’s okay I’ve figured it out, I’ve secured the DELETE query as x key is and 80 character random value in the database the query is for an admin panel which has access controls to who can do what, the images are now hashed as sha256-hmac and displayed on the site as encode base64 the problem was it was getting the wrong picture id’s as the $eg_Result1[‘id’] was not in the repeating region where the records are displayed, thanks for your help everyone it’s much appreciated